# Connecting Slick 3.2.1 to MySQL using slick.jdbc.MySQLProfile

Tags: scala, slick, slick-3.0

There are 100s of threads on SO on how to connect slick to Mysql and all of them use "slick.driver.MySQLDriver$". I believe that this class is now deprecated and has been replaced by "slick.jdbc.MySQLProfile"

This has been stated by the product documentation here

http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.2.1/api/#slick.driver.package

So in order to use the new class I define my configuration as

```
mysql = {
  driver = "slick.jdbc.MySQLProfile"
  properties = {
    driver = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
    url  = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/foo"
    user = "foo"
    password = "bar"
  }
}

Database.forConfig("mysql")
```

But I get an exception

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to load class of driverClassName slick.jdbc.MySQLProfile
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig.setDriverClassName(HikariConfig.java:323)
        at slick.jdbc.hikaricp.HikariCPJdbcDataSource$.$anonfun$forConfig$3(HikariCPJdbcDataSource.scala:31)
        at slick.jdbc.hikaricp.HikariCPJdbcDataSource$.$anonfun$forConfig$3$adapted(HikariCPJdbcDataSource.scala:31)
        at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
        at slick.jdbc.hikaricp.HikariCPJdbcDataSource$.forConfig(HikariCPJdbcDataSource.scala:31)
```

I tried many other combinations but nothing seems to work for the new class. So what is the right way to connect now when slick.driver.MySQLDriver$ is deprecated?

Here is my libraryDependencies from build.sbt

```
"com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "3.2.1",
"com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick-hikaricp" % "3.2.1",
"com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick-codegen" % "3.2.1",
"mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.34",
```

yes I do need the connection pool.

Edit: Based on suggestion below I changed my config to

```
mysql = {
  profile = "slick.jdbc.MySQLProfile$"
  properties = {
    driver = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
    url  = "jdbc:mysql://local:3306/foo"
    user = "foo"
    password = "bar"
  }
}
```

but now I get error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: dataSource or dataSourceClassName or jdbcUrl is required.
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig.validate(HikariConfig.java:786)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.<init>(HikariDataSource.java:67)
        at slick.jdbc.hikaricp.HikariCPJdbcDataSource$.forConfig(HikariCPJdbcDataSource.scala:58)
        at slick.jdbc.hikaricp.HikariCPJdbcDataSource$.forConfig(HikariCPJdbcDataSource.scala:21)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [documentation](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.2.1/database.html#databaseconfig) suggests to put this in your config:

```
profile = "slick.jdbc.MySQLProfile$"
```

Note the `$` at the end of the line.

Also, add the following to [enable connection pooling](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.2.1/database.html#using-a-database-url):

```
dataSourceClass = "slick.jdbc.DatabaseUrlDataSource"
```

Answer (score 12):

Here is the full working config if anyone needs it

```
mysql = {
  profile = "slick.jdbc.MySQLProfile$"
  dataSourceClass = "slick.jdbc.DatabaseUrlDataSource"
  properties = {
    driver = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
    url  = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/foo"
    user = "foo"
    password = "bar"
  }
}
```

full build.sbt

```
"com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "3.2.1",
"com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick-hikaricp" % "3.2.1",
"com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick-codegen" % "3.2.1",
"mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.34",
```

connection established using

```
Database.forConfig("mysql")
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing, saved me some time

Comment: Note that recently the class name for mysql jdbc driver has changed to `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver`

Answer (score 2):

**Using HikariCP Pool**

***application.conf***

```
slick {
  profile = "slick.jdbc.MySQLProfile$"
  db {
    connectionPool = "HikariCP"
    url = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/abc"
    user = "user"
    password = "passabc"
    driver = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
    numThreads = 5
    maxConnections = 5
    minConnections = 1
  }
}
```

***build.sbt***

```
"com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % slickVersion,
"com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick-hikaricp" % slickVersion,
"mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "8.0.15",
```